# How to config Firebase Crashlytics in Ionic 3 and cordova-ios@4.5.4?

Tags: node.js, firebase, ionic3, crashlytics, cordova-ios

I work on a project which needs the implementation of Firebase Crashlytics in Ionic 3.

We studied all the documentation but we faced some issues about the integration of cordova-ios.

Due to the project being hybrid, we need to use firebase plugins to be able to generate non-fatal error log handling in the app.

Ionic 5 lists cordova-plugin-firebase-crashlytics plugin in its documentation but when trying to install it on ionic 3 with cordova-ios@4.5.4, a warning about cordova-ios incompatibility is displayed.

The installation of the firebase crashlytics plugin in Ionic 3 is downgraded to a previous version, when continuing the documentation step by step, we encounter an Injectable error and we are unable to progress.

We have few questions:

- Which version of node is required for cordova-ios@5.0.0?
- Has some firebase plugin for the use of Firebase Crashlytics in cordova-ios@4.5.4?
- Firebase Crashlytics also requires configuration in native project files and Xcode in order to communicate with the Firebase console. How can we dynamically configure Crashlytics configuration files in Ionic's platforms folder?

Comment: We dropped cordova-plugin-firebase-crashlytics in favor of https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-crash
we also experienced a lot of problems with that plugin

Comment: Our project cordova's version is 8.1.2 and the plugin suggested requires a version higher than 10.0.0. Do you know other way to using it?